# Differential operator as sum of Dirac delta functions

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta, differential-operators

For $x \in [0,1]$, let
$$\tilde{G}(x) = \frac{1}{2(e - 1)}(e^x + e^{1-x})$$

And let $G(x)$ be the 1-periodic extension of $\tilde{G}(x)$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Show that, in the sense of distributions, we have
$$G'' + G = \sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} \delta_z.$$

---

This is a simplification of a question from an exam from a couple years ago on spectral theory. The question appears in the context of showing that the laplacian is self-adjoint with Born-von Karman boundary conditions.

I'm (extra) confused by the fact that $G(x)$ is a function extended to all or $\mathbb{R}$. My feeble attempt is to write $G(x)$ as
$$G(x) = \sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{1}_{x\in [z,z+1]} \tilde{G}(x-z)$$

And then somehow do something with the Fourier transform:
$$\langle \mathfrak{F}(G'' + G), \phi \rangle = \dots
= \sum \langle \mathbb{1}, \phi \rangle$$

But honestly I have no idea.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/solutions.

Comment: Calculate $\tilde{G}'' + \tilde{G}$ on $(0, 1)$. What do you get?
Is $G$ continuous? Is $G'$ continuous?

Comment: It seems OP's eq. should read $G-G'' = \sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} \delta_z$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Everything is continuous. And the sign before $G''$ is positive, but maybe I missed something somewhere. I'm thinking now that I need to express $G$ as a Fourier series.